# How to find specific file types and tar them?

Tags: linux, files, find, tar

It seems I've got a problem. I've got some different file types in my current directory, and I want to just **tar** the **.png** files. I started with this:

```
find -name "*.png" | tar -cvf backupp.tar
```

It wouldn't work because I didn't specify which files, so looking on how others did it, I added xargs:

```
find -name "*.png" | xargs tar -cvf backupp.tar
```

It did work this time, and backupp.tar file was created, but here is the problem. I can't seem to extract it. Whenever I type:

```
tar -xvf backupp.tar
```

Nothings happens. I've tried changing chmod and sudo, but nothing gives in.

So, did I type the wrong command completely or is there somethings I just missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of your two approaches was close to working, but each had a distinct problem.

In your first approach you try to pipe a list of files to `tar`. If you want `tar` to read the list of files from standard input then you have to use the `-T`/`--files-from` and `-` options, e.g.

```bsh
find -name '*.png' -print0 | tar -cvf backup.tar --null -T -
```

For a reference, see the official documentation:

- [GNU tar Manual: Section 6.3 - Reading Names from a File](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/files.html#SEC107)

**NOTE:** The use of the `-print0` and `--null` flags should ensure that this also handles filenames which include whitespace.

In your second approach you try to run `tar` via `xargs`, but you're using the "create" option (`--create` / `-c`). If you use the "create" option with `xargs` or in a for-loop, then it will overwrite the archive after every iteration. Instead, try using either the "append" option (`-a` / `--append`) or the "update" option (`-u` / `--update`), e.g.:

```
find -name "*.png" -exec tar -uvf backupp.tar {} \;
```

This will append files to the archive after each iteration instead of over-writing it.

Either way, once you're done you can use the "list" option (`--list` / `-t`) to view the contents of the archive and verify that everything worked as expected:

```
tar tf backupp.tar
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the wildcard

```
tar -cvf backup.tar *.png
```

or by using `find`

```
find -name "*.png" | tar -cvf backup.tar -T -
```

the `-T` option gets the file name from FILE which in this case is stdin `-`